# How to quit shortly after starting in the best possible way?

Tags: job-change

I spent last months searching for jobs. The positions I applied for are mid-level white-collar jobs.

This week I've started a job I wan't sure I should accept. The first reason was it's a temporary position for 10 months and I was looking for something stable. The second reason was the position is only partly related to what I had done before. It's a partial diversion from my career track. The third reason was it seems more junior than what I had done before.

The company was keeping me waiting for the contract till my first day. As I didn't have the contract till Monday, I kept applying for other positions.

My first impression at the company is ok, but my expectations concerning the position being quite junior have been confirmed, although my line manager seems open for the role to develop into something more advanced. I'm afraid it's a bit of a dead-end thing as I have a very different background than... basically everybody and even if after 10 months I wanted to stay with the company it's not clear where I could work.

However, now I've got an offer for a position that corresponds perfectly to what I had been doing before. It focuses on my hitherto focus. It's much more senior than what I have now and than my positions so far. Contrary to the position I've now started, I wouldn't be doing myself so much, I would be managing people doing things and defining strategy. It almost sounds too good to be true.

I need to quit at my current company. I feel really bad about it, my reputation is important to me and I understand that my quitting I show I can't be counted on. I understand I provoked costs. I like the company. I've met friendly people. But the other position seems like a much better option.

How would you do that to provoke as little problems as possible?

Comment: What exactly did you get from the other company, a verbal offer, a contract? And what is your country?

Comment: Tell them that with a recession incoming, you want something stable.